# Android 6.0+ java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

Recently， I have met a really strange problem about permission issue, it confused me a few days, I hope someone will help me figure out what is going on. Thanks!

Here is the problem:
For some reason, I need to apply the storage permission for save some photos, and I had added the permission to the `AndroidManifestival.xml:`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Off course, I knew I have to apply for storage permission in code after **Android 6.0**, and here is my code for apply for permission:

```
public static boolean isGrantExternalRW(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (context.checkSelfPermission(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        ((Activity)context).requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I had use this method before I saved photo, and the permission dialog had shown up and I had checked it. And I had checked the app permission in the app setting, it's ok.

And here is the method I used to save the bitmap to the file:

```
public static String savePhotoToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String photoName) {
    String absolutePath = "";

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.e("file", "---------------------" + state);
    File newsDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + File.separator + "photo");


    if (!newsDir.exists()) {
        newsDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File picFile = new File(newsDir, photoName + ".png");
    absolutePath = picFile.getAbsolutePath();

    if (picFile.exists()) {
        picFile.delete();
    }

    if (photoName.equals("avatar")) {          
        int ratio = 2;        
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth() / ratio, bitmap.getHeight() / ratio, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / ratio, bitmap.getHeight() / ratio);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
        if (bitmap != null) {

            if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, fileOutputStream)) {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                Log.d("Photo", "---------------------------fileOutputStream.flush");
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("File", "----------------------------" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return absolutePath;
}
```

When I ran the app, it went wrong, here is the log：

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/photo/avatar.png(permission denied)

But the most strange thing was that when I add the storage permission twice to AndroidManifestival.xml,  it worked!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So, what's the problem? Please help.

Comment: try again with removing first set of permissions and see the same problem occurs again or not

Comment: `FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/android/mktaid/avatar.png` ? That is not a possible path if you used the code you posted. As it does not match `File newsDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + File.separator + "photo");`.

Comment: Moreover a path like `/storage/emulated/0/android/.....` cannot exist as there is already a `/storage/emulated/0/Android` directory.

Comment: I had removed first set of permissions but the problem was occured again

Comment: I put the wrong log before, now I corrected

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: `newsDir.mkdirs(); `. Change to `if(!  newsDir.mkdirs()){Toast(...sorry cannot create directory...); return;}`

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, I solved my problem finally. Here was the reason:
The storage permission conflicts with the dependency below:

```
compile 'com.github.vungle:vungle-android-sdk:5.3.0'
```

When I added the dependency, system cannot recognized the storage permission which I have apply for(while I added twice in AndroidManifest.xml, it worked), but when I removed it, everything was ok ! This dependency was used to add ad into app, but now I have to abandon it.

Comment: Yes i also had vungle library integrated, its working.Strange Issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is similar to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Have you [handled the permissions request response](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#handle-response)?

Related to these links you have to implement these steps correctly in your code:

***First:*** try to use this to request the permission:

```
 boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission......) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    if(permissionGranted) {
        // {Some Code}
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission....}, 200);
    }
```

***Second:*** implementation of `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`

```
...implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
```

***Third:*** override `onRequestPermissionsResult` method

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // {Some Code}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17888965)

Comment: @Grimthorr can you check the last edit ? and give me a feedback

Comment: There is no need to implement onRequestPermissionResult(). The result is granted or not. Independend from if you add that function. And OP said that in Settings the toggle was ON. So i do not understand that you even started to talk about permissions.

Comment: @Grimthorr : in my turn, I would like to thank you for your support !

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez The edited answer is much better. However, I think it was also flagged because the content doesn't quite match the question. This is why link-only answers are normally better suited as a comment until you're sure the question can be answered from information in the link.

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez  I had try onRequestPermissionResult(), but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

call this method in splash screen or where you open camera .

```
 public static boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context context) {
                int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                int readfilePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                int writefilePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                }
                        if (readfilePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                if (writefilePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

In AndroidManifestival.xml you need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this, i think you are deleting the file as soon as you are creating it.

```
if (new File(newsDir, photoName + ".png").exists()) {
       new File(newsDir, photoName + ".png").delete();
}
File picFile = new File(newsDir, photoName + ".png");
absolutePath = picFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

and in the place of

```
Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory().toString()
use this 
Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory().getabsolutepath()
```